# How can I insert a basic Search bar in Material UI Data Grid?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datagridview, hyperlink, material-ui

For example: [refer this sample data grid.](https://codesandbox.io/s/4be7oi?file=/demo.js)

Want to add a basic search bar like:[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M33Vt.png)

How can I add in Data Grid MUI.
Please guide.

Answer (score 3):

In datagrid there is prop components and Toolbar in that prop to pass whatever component you want.

```js
components={{ Toolbar: QuickSearchToolbar }}
```

and pass props from

```js
componentsProps={{
  toolbar: {
    value: searchText,
    onChange: (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => handleSearch
  },
}}
```

This is a good example to check out:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import IconButton from '@mui/material/IconButton';
import TextField from '@mui/material/TextField';
import {
  DataGrid,
  GridToolbarDensitySelector,
  GridToolbarFilterButton,
} from '@mui/x-data-grid';
import { useDemoData } from '@mui/x-data-grid-generator';
import ClearIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Clear';
import SearchIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Search';
import { createTheme } from '@mui/material/styles';
import { createStyles, makeStyles } from '@mui/styles';

function escapeRegExp(value: string): string {
  return value.replace(/[-[\]{}()*+?.,\\^$|#\s]/g, '\\$&');
}

const defaultTheme = createTheme();
const useStyles = makeStyles(
  (theme) =>
    createStyles({
      root: {
        padding: theme.spacing(0.5, 0.5, 0),
        justifyContent: 'space-between',
        display: 'flex',
        alignItems: 'flex-start',
        flexWrap: 'wrap',
      },
      textField: {
        [theme.breakpoints.down('xs')]: {
          width: '100%',
        },
        margin: theme.spacing(1, 0.5, 1.5),
        '& .MuiSvgIcon-root': {
          marginRight: theme.spacing(0.5),
        },
        '& .MuiInput-underline:before': {
          borderBottom: `1px solid ${theme.palette.divider}`,
        },
      },
    }),
  { defaultTheme },
);

interface QuickSearchToolbarProps {
  clearSearch: () => void;
  onChange: () => void;
  value: string;
}

function QuickSearchToolbar(props: QuickSearchToolbarProps) {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <div>
        <GridToolbarFilterButton />
        <GridToolbarDensitySelector />
      </div>
      <TextField
        variant="standard"
        value={props.value}
        onChange={props.onChange}
        placeholder="Search…"
        className={classes.textField}
        InputProps={{
          startAdornment: <SearchIcon fontSize="small" />,
          endAdornment: (
            <IconButton
              title="Clear"
              aria-label="Clear"
              size="small"
              style={{ visibility: props.value ? 'visible' : 'hidden' }}
              onClick={props.clearSearch}
            >
              <ClearIcon fontSize="small" />
            </IconButton>
          ),
        }}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

export default function QuickFilteringGrid() {
  const { data } = useDemoData({
    dataSet: 'Commodity',
    rowLength: 100,
    maxColumns: 6,
  });
  const [searchText, setSearchText] = React.useState('');
  const [rows, setRows] = React.useState<any[]>(data.rows);

  const requestSearch = (searchValue: string) => {
    setSearchText(searchValue);
    const searchRegex = new RegExp(escapeRegExp(searchValue), 'i');
    const filteredRows = data.rows.filter((row: any) => {
      return Object.keys(row).some((field: any) => {
        return searchRegex.test(row[field].toString());
      });
    });
    setRows(filteredRows);
  };

  React.useEffect(() => {
    setRows(data.rows);
  }, [data.rows]);

  return (
    <div style={{ height: 400, width: '100%' }}>
      <DataGrid
        components={{ Toolbar: QuickSearchToolbar }}
        rows={rows}
        columns={data.columns}
        componentsProps={{
          toolbar: {
            value: searchText,
            onChange: (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) =>
              requestSearch(event.target.value),
            clearSearch: () => requestSearch(''),
          },
        }}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just create a search bar using a label and text input. Aftermath you can update your grid according to the string in your search box by the search filtered data.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).